# y como puedo hacer formulas mas avanzadas con inputs

Tags: javascript, html, variables, script, get

por ejemplo aqui remplase una ecuacion por inputs que los converti en variables y estas los queria utilizar para realizar operaciones avanzadas pero no me sale que tenga algun error y tampoco me sale el resultado

```js
   function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value; 
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 

  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  
  result.value = parseInt("a") - (parseInt("b")*(1.224/250*parseInt("c")*28));
}
```

```html
<form oninput="calc()">
    <input id="a" type="number" value="0">
    <input id="b" type="number" value="0">
    <input id="c" type="number" value="0">
    <output id="result"></output>
    </form>
```

Comment: Si te fue de ayuda mi respuesta marcala como aceptada, así los demás usuarios que tengan el mismo problema sabrán por donde empezar.

Answer (score 4):

El error es que estás haciendo un `parseInt()` de un string `"a"` cuando debería de ser tu variable `a` que estás declarando y así con la variable `b` y `c`.

```js
function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value; 
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 

  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  
  result.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*28));
}
```

```html
<form oninput="calc()">
    <input id="a" type="number" value="0">
    <input id="b" type="number" value="0">
    <input id="c" type="number" value="0">
    <output id="result"></output>
    </form>
```